# как сделать так что бы в text. При вызове писалась имя пользователя который нажал на кнопку

Tags: python, pycharm

Учусь делать клавишу назад в кнопке.
Как сделать так, чтобы в text при вызове писалась имя пользователя который нажал на кнопку?

```py
bot.edit_message_text(
    chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
    text=("Привіт " + call.message.message_id.from_user.first_name +
          "!" +
          "\n Я допоможу тобі роз  рахувати твій конкурсний бал  ... "),
    reply_markup=keyboardg)
```

Код

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "mainmenu":
        keyboardg = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

        callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="Так ✔ ️", callback_data="test")

        callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="Ні ❌ ", callback_data="test_1")

        keyboardg.add(callback_button, callback_button_1)

        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text=("Привіт " + call.message.message_id.from_user.first_name +
                  "!" +
                  "\n Я допоможу тобі роз  рахувати твій конкурсний бал  ... "),
            reply_markup=keyboardg)
```

Comment: Научись уже нормально форматировать вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените `call.message.message_id.from_user.first_name`   на  `call.message.from_user.first_name`

```
 bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                  text="Привіт " + call.message.from_user.first_name + "!" +
                                       "\n Я допоможу тобі роз  рахувати твій конкурсний бал  ... ",
                                  reply_markup=keyboardg)
```